# Is it possible to prevent some attributes from being marshalled with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I need some value to be changed only via the xml file.

In other words, we have something like:

```
<Settings>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <property>something</property>
</Settings>
```

and I want the enabled value to be only manipulated in the xml file. So I want all the values to be loaded from the file (unmarshalled), but I want JAXB to leave the original  value that was in the file and only output (marshal) other values to the file.

Scenario where this can be required is from example if while something was being processed, I want to modify the xml file manually, and disable something, but don't want JAXB to later overwrite this particular value, but of course all other values need to be written to the file after processing to be up to date.

Is it possible to achieve this with JAXB?

Comment: marshalling works that way. i think you will have to do _manual process_ after marshalling, so that you overwrite what has been marshalled.